# Can you identify this mosquitoe-like bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, invasive-species

I'm wondering what is this bug, I have never seen it before and its behaviour is just weird for me, they just try to climb to the top of the window, then fall and start over again, I see no hole they are going through, they seem capable of flying but they don't.

[image: Bug size comparison]
[image: Closeup]
(click to enlarge images)

Please help me know:

A) Which bug is it?

B) Is it harmful?

C) What business do they have with my window (What is attracting them?)

D) How do I get rid of them?

I'm in Mexico City and it was rainy up until this last days when they arrived, now it is warm, also I have some plants in the room but they don't seem to be interested to go near them.

Comment: Interestingly, one turned up on our kitchen table this afternoon. (Southern UK). Never knowingly seen one before. So, *watching*.

Comment: Unsure, but looks to be part of a mating swarm of ants. Not a problem if so.

Comment: Also unsure, but I think it's some kind of two-winged fly (_Diptera_); an in-focus photo showing wing venation would be a big help, but I suspect they're no longer around (it's been three weeks since this inquiry; the flight season for this critter might already be over).